# Making sub-categories within a table

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have a large database built on REDCap which includes a question regarding diagnosis category, with a follow-on branching logic question regarding the exact diagnosis according to category.

Here is a reprex:

```
reprex <- read.csv(text = "record_id,diagnosis_category,infection_diagnosis,cardiology_diagnosis,neurology_diagnosis\n1,infection,pneumonia,,\n2,cardiology,,arrhythmia,\n3,infection,uti,,\n4,cardiology,,heart_attack,\n5,neurology,,,stroke\n6,infection,cellulitis,,")
```

I am struggling to make this into a table with tbl_summary().

I want to a make a table which shows the overall breakdown of diagnoses according to category, with a sub-category showing the detailed diagnosis for each category.

Any advice?!

I have tried to make a tbl_summary() as follows, but the blank cells get included in the analysis. I would also ideally like to make each detailed diagnosis a sub-category in the row below the diagnosis group.

```
reprex |> select(!record_id) |> tbl_summary(sort = all_categorical() ~ 'frequency')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to get correctly, I think replacing the blank cells and adding a group to the `tbl_summary` function gets you what you need:

```
reprex %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(.x == "", NA_character_, .x))) %>% 
  select(!record_id) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = diagnosis_category, 
              missing = "no", 
              type = list(infection_diagnosis ~ "categorical", cardiology_diagnosis ~ "categorical", neurology_diagnosis ~ "categorical"))
```